# Modifying footnotes in R blogdown

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown, tufte

I am tinkering with the [tuftesque](https://github.com/nstrayer/tuftesque) theme for R blogdown. I would like to change the way footnotes are rendered such that they become part of the sidenotes that are typical for Tufte's format.

If I add some text with a footnote

```
This is supposed to be a standard text^[Check this footnote] with a footnote then yada yada yada
```

then the footnote is rendered at the end of the page. This is not particular to the `tuftesque` package - this is standard for R markdown. The code above is rendered as

```
<div class="footnotes">
<hr />
<ol>
<li id="fn1"><p>Check this footnote<a href="#fnref1">↩</a></p></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Is it possible to tweak blogdown (or pandoc) to make sure the footnotes are added in place instead of at the end of the document so I can replicate the layout seen below (picture is from the `tufte` package where things are rendered correctly).

[image]